# Javascript regex, ignore one specific character

Tags: javascript

I'm using this regex to allow everything up to 4000 chars.

`/^[\s\S]{0,4000}$/`

How can I not allow semi-colons?

I tried `/^[^\;\s\S]{0,4000}$/`

e.g.

aaaa -> should work

aaaa; -> should not work

aa;aa -> should not work

but it''s not working. any help?

Comment: Where is your JavaScript code?

Comment: `^` inside square brackets is valid for all the `[ ]` content, you can't mix it with your search of strings with `\s`

Comment: I'm using ng-pattern. Nothing else.

Comment: It works if you take out the `\s\S`.

Comment: maybe this will be easier and more efficient to just look for prohibited characters inside the string with `indexOf`

Answer (score 0):

The character class `[\s\S]` matches everything. The [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^\s\S]` matches nothing. You want `[^;]` - everything that's not a semicolon.

Comment: any idea why`\s\S` was there (i didnt do the code)? this was supposed to allow everything

Comment: @TiagoSilva Yes, it did allow everything, it did work. Notice that the `^`  negates the *entire* character class, not just the next character.